# How to add an attribute to the result of the LDAP search in perl

Tags: perl, ldap, ldap-query

I do an LDAP search and as a result of it i get entries.

In some of the entries an attribute is missing(say atrribute "o").

I need to add this "o" attribute to the entries which is missing it.

Note: I do not need to update this value to the LDAP Server. I just need to add this attribute "o" along with a value in the resultant variable which i have as a search result.

I have the below code:

```
 if($entry->exists('o')){
      func($entry);//this funtion manipulates the entry
 }
 else{
      # I need the code here to add the "o" attribute and a value to the $entry
      func($entry);
 }
```

How to add this attribute "o" to the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the entry is an [Net::LDAP::Entry](http://search.cpan.org/~marschap/perl-ldap-0.64/lib/Net/LDAP/Entry.pod) object?  If so, you should be able to add an attribute by calling "add":

```
$entry->add( 'o' => 'new value' );
```

So your example would look like this:

```
if($entry->exists('o')){
      func($entry);//this funtion manipulates the entry
}
else{
      $entry->add( 'o' => 'new value' );
      func($entry);
}
```